# Novo logo do meta está fora do sitio

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, imagem

O novo logo do meta está deslocada em relação ao site principal, ao Stack Overflow em inglês e ao meta do inglês.

Por baixo está a logo no meta e acima exatamente o mesmo *screenshot* com 50% de opacidade a do site principal.


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

O `span` `meta-title` não existe no site principal, mas removendo do DOM não faz diferença no posicionamento:

[image]

Comment: Não consigo ver isso... pode postar um par de imagens?

Comment: @brasofilo É difícil. Abre 2 abas com o SOpt e o meta e passa rapidamente duma para a outra verás que o logo não está no mesmo sitio. Agora repete isso mas com o SOen e o meta en.

Comment: Ah, agora vi. E como diabos vc conseguiu reparar nisso? Obs.: sofro de déficit de atenção, :(

Comment: @Earendul eu abro sempre o meta e o site ao lado um e outros sites da rede, quando venho passar os olhos passo uma aba de cada vez e notei.

Comment: Jorge, confere se ficou legal... talvez fosse bom colocar a tradução (?)

Comment: @brasofilo a imagem atrofia-me todo :P Estas a vontade de editar e colocar a tradução se quiseres. Muito bem +1. Wait não posso dar +1 :D

Comment: Na verdade, não tenho muita disposição para traduzir porque não sei se isto é exatamente um *bug*... não atrapalha nada e, ao contrário do @Earendul, só quem tem superavit de atenção consegue ver :P

Comment: @brasofilo o m0sa já viu este bug e editou a tag, por isso ele deve ter percebido o problema.

Comment: we're going to fix this soon.

Comment: @Jin thanks for replay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto) It's now fixed and will be live after our next production build.